# Ocultar divs padre si div hijo tiene cierto texto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un archivo html con mas de 3500 `div` y necesito crear una función con jQuery que me oculte los `div` padres si un `div` hijo tiene cierto texto (p.e.: "codigo"). ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Ésta es mi función, pero no logro que funcione adecuadamente:

```
$(".comment").contents( function(){ 
  if (this.value === 0) {
    this.parent.css( "display","none");
  }
});
```

Por ejemplo- quisiera que se oculte el `div` padre del `div` con clase "attributeName" y que contenga el texto "codigo":

```js
$(".comment").contents(function() {
  if (this.value === 0) {
    this.parent.css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="attribute">
    <div class="attributeName">AAA</div>
    <div class="attributeComment"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="attribute">
    <div class="attributeName">codigo</div>
    <div class="attributeComment"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="attribute">
    <div class="attributeName">BBB</div>
    <div class="attributeComment"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="attribute">
    <div class="attributeName">CCCC</div>
    <div class="attributeComment"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Mas de 3000 divs con las mismas clases -->
```

Answer (score -1):

hola esto deberia funcionarte

```
$(".attributeName").each(function( index ){
    if($(this).html()=="codigo"){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu respuesta y agrega alguna descripción a este código. Lee [cómo escribir una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Mauricio no entendi muy bien a que te refieres,ya que el codigo es muy corto y se explica solo, podrias publicar una respuesta acorde con tus estandares si la mia no te satisface yo no busco ganar reputacion ni nada de eso solo ayudar a la gente.

Comment: esta respuesta apareció en la cola de publicaciones de baja calidad. Esto sucede cuando se detecta que la publicación es sólo código o poco texto. Cuando publiques preguntas o respuestas, debes incluir una explicación del código *(no se trata solamente de publicar código)*.

Comment: gracias por el bulling, comentario ignorado

Comment: Hola @reftferreiras, el comentario de Mauricio no es bullying y no deberías ignorarlo, te está intentado ayudar indicando un problema real con tu publicación. La respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido, deberías editarla para añadir algo más de información (p.e. una breve descripción de qué hace el código y cómo solucionar el problema expuesto en la pregunta). Lee [answer] para más información.